# Linux: Environment Variable setting to ignore case sensitivity?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I'm stuck with a question for my Linux lab, if you can help.

> It is required to determine which 'environment variable' that would
>   modify the grep command to be case-insensitive. Then change this
>   environment variable appropriately using the syntax “ export
>   VARIABLE=value ”  (in bash). Finally, execute the command “grep a <<<
>   A ” to show that grep now ignores case

`greps` option are not helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep looks at the envirorment variable GREP_OPTIONS
so you can do

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--ignore-case"
grep a <<< "A"
```